# Big gap in between sewing

Tags: cloth-simulation

[image]

Hi, there seems to be a big gap where the two planes are supposed to meet. I have attached 2 pictures which shows the settings for the cloth simulation and sewing effect[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clothing simply isn’t large enough to fit around your model. Either increase the garment’s size or decrease the ‘Outer’ in the collision mesh’s Collision settings.

Comment: I've tried that but the gap still remains

Comment: Is there any difference at all? Maybe post some further images to show the difference. The other option is to increase your sewing force or increase the stretchiness of the cloth. Surely making the clothing bigger must have had some impact. Don’t forget to Apply Scale after any changes and also to Free and re-Bake your simulation.

Comment: How do I increase the stretchiness of the cloth?

Comment: I usually work with Soft Body so not too familiar with Cloth.... I think reducing the Stiffness settings - in particular Tension, Shear and Bending should allow your cloth to 'give' a little.

Comment: I forgot to 'apply scale'. It works :)